# How to get appdata after re-installing the app in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I've created an application and installed in my iPhone and later deleted the app. The data of the app was also deleted from the device. If I re-install the app in my device, can my app get back the data which was deleted previously? If yes, how can my app get it back?

Comment: It depends. What kind of data do you want to get ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I've saved a sqlite file in my apps docs folder.How can i get it back?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: @rmaddy It depends on how you look at it.

Comment: @Undo As written, this is a user-level question.

Comment: @rmaddy How's it look now?

Comment: @Undo On what basis did you make those edits? You are now making many assumptions about the OP's original meaning. Those changes need to be rolled back. Let the OP update their own question if needed.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm basing it off of the OP's first comment - a SQLite file in the Documents folder? Not end-user.

Comment: You could enable [file-sharing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH10-SW30) to let users to do backups.